# How to use react GitHub repository code in my my react application?

Tags: reactjs, github, repository, code-reuse, github-codespaces

I want to use react github repository in my react application project how I can do this please brief me.

I want to use any react github repoistory in my react project but I don't know how I can do this. I have cloned the repository and saved it in a directory but now I am confused how I can use it in my react project because it is different react app and the my project is different react app then how I can use it in my react project?